# Visual C++ 2008. Не удается открыть файл include: chrono / thread

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Работаю в Visual Studio 2008 C++. Для проекта нужны две библиотеки `chrono` и `thread`. Ну при построение, возникает ошибка:

```
main.h(11) : fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл include: chrono: No such file or directory
main.h(11) : fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть файл include: thread: No such file or directory
```

Решил проверить, есть ли они на самом деле - есть.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Harry, Вот как раз, я это не знаю.

Comment: chrono и thread были добавлены в стандарте 2011 года и нашлись они у вас в папке Visual Studio 2015

Comment: @user7860670, можно их как-то вручную добавить?

Comment: Нет, ведь для их работы требуется поддержка c++11 со стороны компилятора

Comment: @user7860670, то есть придётся скачать visual studio 2011?

Comment: У вас же уже есть  Visual Studio 2015... А вообще сейчас актуальна 2019